# How to create public String Replace with 4 methods

Tags: c#

In .NET Core 2.0, .NET Core 3.1 there is a string with four overloads. I have a class library project where I need to use that replacement string. Unfortunately, my target framework is 4.6 and the System String doesn't seem to have a "String.Replace" with four overloads as in the below code. Is there any way that I could use a replace string in perhaps an extension for Visual Studio 2015 C#?

I've only been able to gather one of the methods from this site and can't figure out the other three. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
        //
    // Parameters:
    //   oldValue:
    //
    //   newValue:
    //
    //   ignoreCase:
    //
    //   culture:
    public String Replace(String oldValue, String newValue, bool ignoreCase, CultureInfo culture);
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   oldValue:
    //
    //   newValue:
    //
    //   comparisonType:
    public String Replace(String oldValue, String newValue, StringComparison comparisonType);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified string in the current
    //     instance are replaced with another specified string.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   oldValue:
    //     The string to be replaced.
    //
    //   newValue:
    //     The string to replace all occurrences of oldValue.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     A string that is equivalent to the current string except that all instances of
    //     oldValue are replaced with newValue. If oldValue is not found in the current
    //     instance, the method returns the current instance unchanged.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   T:System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     oldValue is null.
    //
    //   T:System.ArgumentException:
    //     oldValue is the empty string ("").
    public String Replace(String oldValue, String newValue);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified Unicode character
    //     in this instance are replaced with another specified Unicode character.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   oldChar:
    //     The Unicode character to be replaced.
    //
    //   newChar:
    //     The Unicode character to replace all occurrences of oldChar.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     A string that is equivalent to this instance except that all instances of oldChar
    //     are replaced with newChar. If oldChar is not found in the current instance, the
    //     method returns the current instance unchanged.
    public String Replace(char oldChar, char newChar);
```

Thank you.

Comment: You could just make your own extension method that would be used the same way?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I looked at what Fruchtzwerg provided. However, I think putting together this extension method is a bit over my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, [.NET Cores String.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netcore-3.1) differs from [.NET Frameworks String.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.6).

You could add the missing functions with your own extensions methods like described at [the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

A good starting point is doing this by checking the implementation of the missing methods in [.NET cores implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/90cc6dff11e4eea07d8b2ed438b25679f0caf7a8/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/String.Manipulation.cs#L969).

So you should be able to implementate the missing method of your needs.

**Udate:**

Let's have a look at your noted calls at SharpHash [here](https://github.com/ron4fun/SharpHash/blob/master/SharpHash/Utils/Converters.cs#L285) and [here](https://github.com/ron4fun/SharpHash/blob/master/SharpHash/Utils/Converters.cs#L290):

```
hex.Replace(delimeter.ToString(), "", true, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

It looks like the goal of this operation is just use `ignoreCase` to deal with hexadecimal input correctly, the culture needs to be set in this case but may be ignored. Knowing this, we could provide a simple alternative implementation as extension method using regex functionalities:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Replace(this string str, string oldValue, string newValue,
        bool ignoreCase, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       return Regex.Replace(str, oldValue, newValue,
           ignoreCase ? RegexOptions.IgnoreCase : RegexOptions.None);
    }
}
```

Note that this implementation is **no full replacement of the original method**, since things like

- Regex language elements in string
- Performance
- Culture

are not observed. But for your problem, the solution should be sufficient. If not, try to extend and modify the solution like required.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I tried copying the methods over into a class. Made the class a partial, but I have a host of things I'm unable to fix because I'm not that knowledgeable in that area; type must be non-nullable, argument 3 cannot be converted, GetCaseCompareOfComparisonCulture does not exist in current context, Invariant does not contain a definition, string extension does not contain a definition, etc. Not sure really understand how to create this method.

Comment: Which overloaded missing implementation do you need? Both of them?

Comment: This String Replace came from a hash project "h**ps://github.com/ron4fun/SharpHash", the Utils older; the Converters.cs class; line 285 and 290. This project is in visual studio 2019 I think and I have Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Thank you very much Fruchtzwerg. I think that did the trick. I appreciate your help. :-).